# Questions about a readonly @property in ARC

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, automatic-ref-counting

In my interface (.h) file, I have

```
@property(readonly) NSString *foo;
```

and in my implementation (.m) file, I have

```
@synthesize foo;
```

With ARC turned on, the compiler gives me this error: **Automatic Reference Counting Issue: ARC forbids synthesizing a property of an Objective-C object with unspecified ownership or storage attribute.**

The error goes away if I add a `strong`, `weak`, or `copy` to the property. Why is this? Why would there be any differences between these things for a *read-only* property, what are those differences, and why does the programmer have to worry about them? Why can’t the compiler intelligently deduce a default setting for a read-only property?

Another question while I’m at it: `strong`, `weak`, or `copy` are the only things that make sense in ARC, right? I shouldn’t be using `retain` and `assign` anymore, should I?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You've declared a `@property` that doesn't have a backing ivar. Thus, when the compiler sees `@synthesize`, it tries to synthesize a backing ivar for you. But you haven't specified what kind of ivar you want. Should it be `__strong`? `__weak`? `__unsafe_unretained`? Originally, the default storage attribute for properties was `assign`, which is the same as `__unsafe_unretained`. Under ARC, though, that's almost *always* the wrong choice. So rather than synthesizing an unsafe ivar, they require you to specify what kind of ivar you want.

Comment: Ah, it’s starting to make somewhat of a sense now. But if I specify `copy` (for a `readwrite` property), will the generated ivar be `__strong` or `__weak`?

Comment: (Actually, `copy` also compiles for a `readonly` property, which seems somewhat strange to me.)

Comment: A `copy` property will synthesize `__strong` ivars. The main reason you can declare `copy` on a `readonly` property is so that you could redeclare it in a class extension to be `readwrite`; in order to do so, everything else must match.

Comment: `@synthesize` is implicitly included by default

Answer (score 5):

With the latest version of Xcode and recent clang compilers, this error no longer occurs.  You can specify a property as `@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSObject *myProperty;` in the interface, synthesize it in the implementation, and the resulting ivar is assumed to be `strong`.  If you want to be explicit or choose weak, you can do so in the original property, like `@property(nonatomic, readonly, retain)`.  Objective-C is incrementally becoming less redundant.

Answer (score 2):

It is here as a declaration to the rest of your code.
When you a access the property of this class from an other part of your code, you need to know if the object you get is strong or weak.

It used to be more obvious when ARC didn't exists, because the programmer needed this information. Now, ARC makes a lot of things transparent, so it is true, you might wonder why it is still here.

> Why can’t the compiler intelligently deduce a default setting for a read-only property?

I assume it would be pretty easy to set the convention that no keyword means `strong` or means `weak`. If it hasn't been done, they surely had a reason.