# arc forbids synthesizing a property of an objective-c object with unspecified storage attribute.(Look At Below)

Tags: iphone, ios5, automatic-ref-counting

i tried hard to solve arc problem when i declared property.

```
@property (readonly) NSMutableDictionary* activeTransfers;

@synthesize activeTransfers;
```

When i declared Property then i got an error.(arc forbids synthesizing a property of an objective-c object with unspecified storage attribute.),What i have to do for solve the problem.

Comment: do you want readonly for public and readwrite as private?

Answer (score 0):

Change your property declaration to:

@property (nonatomic,strong) NSMutableDictionary* activeTransfers;
& then check.

Comment: i got 10 more erros by using above Changes.

Comment: ok try this @property (nonatomic,retain) NSMutableDictionary* activeTransfers;

Comment: @property (nonatomic,readonly) NSMutableDictionary* activeTransfers; try this.

Comment: only declare it @property (readonly,strong) NSMutableDictionary* activeTransfers; don't synthesize & check...

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716840/questions-about-a-readonly-property-in-arc

Comment: @Nikunj Couldn't you happen to be ***learning Objective-C before complaining to others and wasting our time?***

Answer (score 0):

Simply use :

```
@property(strong) NSMutableDictionary *activeTransfers;
```

And no need to synthesize in .m

Comment: :- Hello I sent mail to u..please check it.it very urjent.